# Быстрое обновление ключей внутри кучи в алгоритме Дейкстры

Tags: алгоритм, haskell

Хочется с нуля реализовать алгоритм Дейкстры на Haskell. Для этого я написал двоичную *кучу* на *дереве*.

При написании самого алгоритма возникла проблема: необходимо для соседей данной вершины обновлять ключи внутри *кучи*.

Каким образом можно на функциональном языке это достаточно быстро сделать, не просматривая всю *кучу*?

Comment: Ну вот тут http://programmingpraxis.com/2011/01/04/dijkstras-algorithm/ используют Data.Map ... (если я правильно понял вопрос)

Comment: @alexlz, да, я видел этот код, как очередь с приоритетами там используется просто список, это не самое лучшее решение, хочется использовать кучу

Comment: Что есть куча? И что значит "просто список"?

Comment: @alexlz куча это [heap][1], обычно двоичная используется для Дейкстры. Фишка в том что извлекается экстремум за O(1), а в списке за O(N). Хотя есть случаи где куча проигрывает (т.к. ее надо перестраивать после извлечения)

ps В книге Кормена она используется в пирамидальной сортировке (где хорошо описана), также можно посмотреть в [школе Яндекса][2] 3ю лекцию (про кучу) и 13 (Дейкстра "+" и "-" выбранной структуры)

 [1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0
 [2]:http://compscicenter.ru/program/course/algorithms2011Fall

Comment: Да уж. Кормена у меня нет, а смотреть видео с Яндекса лениво. Так что ваши страдания как-то непонятны.

Comment: @alexlz страдания? вы о чем? если вы о том, что я ответил, то я тогда могу спросить к чему эти вопросы были? А так мне не жалко минуты на написание (тем более это всего лишь комментарий), может кто откроет для себя реально интересные лекции Яндекса

Comment: @rasmisha Ну неохота мне видео смотреть. Я лекции плохо воспринимаю. 

Если Вы приведёте текст (на императивном языке программирования или на псевдокоде), то можно попытаться на этом примере ответить на начальный вопрос.

А что касается Ваших куч, посмотрите на Data.Map (Data.IntMap, хотя второе для действительных длин рёбер не подойдёт). Внутри они как раз двоичные деревья и интерфейс имеют вполне подходящий.

Comment: Вроде бы есть и [куча][1], хотя подозреваю, что Map тоже может быть реализован подобным образом. Смысл кучи простой, она тоже сбалансированное двоичное дерево, в котором каждый узел это экстремум (элемент с наибольшим приоритетом) своего поддерева. Соответственно, чтобы найти этот лучший элемент, нам надо просто взять первый узел в дереве. А вообще мне кажется имея код даже на простых списках должно быть не сложно переделать его под кучу, тем более если есть такая структура данных

 [1]:http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/heap/0.5.0/doc/html/Data-Heap.html

Answer (score 4):

Нужна структура поддерживающая следующее:

- добавление нового значения за O(logN)
- узнать минимальный элемент за O(1)
- удалить минимальный элемент за O(logN)
- изменить значение элемента за O(logN)

Будем хранить кроме стандартной кучи, массив valueToIndex[v] = index , в котором для каждой вершины v, храниться указатель/индекс на элемент в куче, где храниться значение времени для этой вершины.

Когда требуется изменить значение в какой то вершине:

1. получаем ссылку на элемент в куче, используя массив valueToIndex
2. изменяем значение
3. т.к. для дейкстры значение может только
   уменьшится, то необходимо пропихнуть вверх данный элемент по
   рекурсии (не более logN подъемов)

Так же во всех стандартных функциях кучи, при изменении расположения элементов необходимо обновлять значения массива valueToIndex[].

Если реализовывать кучу не на массивах, то необходимо хранить ссылку на предка.

Если какой то момент не понятен, то распишу подробней.